# Changing the background color of dataframe indexes inside Jupyter Notebooks

Tags: html, css, pandas, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

While using **Jupyter notebooks**, I like to change the **color of header cells** in **Pandas dataframes** (all index cells, up and left) for more contrast between the indexes and the data itself (especially when I'm dealing with **multiple indexes** after using `.groupby()` like in the picture below) :

[image example of colored indexes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BvvvM.png)

I used to achieve this using this CSS code (it works by simply running the cell. This is useful because I often use jupyter notebooks that are hosted on the cloud) :

```css
%%HTML
<style> 
.dataframe th {
background: #3f577c ;
font-family: monospace ;
color: white ;
border: 3px solid white ;
text-align: left !important ; } 
</style>
```

This worked because every index cell (in all indexes, up and left) used to be represented by a `<th> </th>` HTML tag.

However, after updating to Pandas version `0.25.1` from version `0.21.x`, the CSS stopped working because they changed the HTML so only the upper index cells (column names) are wrapped in `<th> <th>` tags. The left index simply uses `<td> </td>` tags, just like the data cells (See image below. Note that both Genre and MediaTypeId are indexes):

[Image showing HTML change before and after Pandas update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9AeBd.jpg)

Is there a way to target the left indexes with CSS? I tried using `first-child` like below but it only worked with dataframes having only 2 indexes (up and left). For the dataframes with more than one index on the left, only the first index is affected :

```css
%%HTML
<style>
.dataframe th, td:first-child {
background: #3f577c ;
font-family: monospace ;
color: white ;
border: 3px solid white ;
text-align: left !important ; }                                             
</style>
```

If there is another way to achieve the effect in the very first picture I'm all ears. Thank you!

**EDIT:** I posted this as an issue in Pandas Github and they told me it was a bug that's probably going to be fixed: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/28204. The issue started with version 0.25.1, so up until version 0.25.0 the CSS should work fine.